# Simple SELECT SQL query not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

Just thought of learning SQL on my own and started  with

**[THIS](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial)**

I was practicing some tutorial and got stuck in one basic query.

After **trying a lot** I could not get it running.

Question is: in which years was the Physics prize awarded but no Chemistry prize.

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics' AND
NOT (Select yr from nobel where subject = 'Chemistry')
```

Can someone help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So close! You just needed `yr` and `IN`:

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics' AND
    yr NOT IN (Select yr from nobel where subject = 'Chemistry')
```

You could also do this with an exclusion join:

```
SELECT yr
FROM nobel n1
LEFT JOIN nobel n2 ON n1.yr = n2.yr AND n2.subject = 'Chemistry'
WHERE n1.subject = 'Physics' AND n2.subject is NULL
```

or a `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel n1
WHERE n1.subject ='Physics' 
  AND NOT EXISTS 
  (
      SELECT NULL 
      FROM nobel n2 
      WHERE n2.subject = 'Chemistry' AND n2.yr=n1.yr
  )
```

Comment: That is one detailed answer. Being noob will try to understand it :) But that was awesomely explained. Thank YOu

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics' AND
yr NOT IN (Select yr from nobel where subject = 'Chemistry')
```

Comment: Thank YOU so much,i was so close. Being noobie is such a headache :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`, to make sure that no row for the same year exists:

```
SELECT yr 
FROM   nobel p
LEFT   JOIN nobel c ON c.yr = p.yr
                   AND c.subject = 'Chemistry'
WHERE  p.subject = 'Physics'
AND    c.yr IS NULL;
```

There are basically 4 techniques:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need that second `AND` condition; cause with that second condition you are just trying to exclude all `yr` where `subject` is `chemistry`. Your query can simply be

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics'
```

Comment: I don't think it should work. Because it will show even the year when Chemistry award was recieved.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics' AND yr
NOT IN(Select yr from nobel where subject = 'Chemistry') GROUP BY yr desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the

NOT (Select yr from nobel where subject = 'Chemistry')

since you are only looking for rows with Physics as subject. You won't need the NOT query since Chemistry will automatically be omitted by the sql query.

Comment: He wants to exclude years where chemistry was also awarded.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics' AND subject <> 'Chemistry'
```

------------Or You can try the below---------------------------

```
SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Physics'

except

SELECT yr 
FROM nobel
WHERE subject ='Chemistry'
```