# Select sql query not working

Tags: mysql

Started solving problems given on sqlzoo.net http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_Nobel_Tutorial

The 8th question given on this tutorial has been solved before on this page [Simple SELECT SQL query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27141821/simple-select-sql-query-not-working)  in extensive detail but I don't understand why my answer is incorrect and giving me wrong results.

My query:

```
    Select distinct yr 
    From (Select distinct yr, subject From nobel Where subject!='Chemistry')X
    Where subject='Physics'
```

Can someone please help explain why my query is not correct?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `!=` to `<>`.

**Edit:**
Removing the **X** actually isn't necessary, as it's acting as a table alias.  But I would fix it to make it more clear by adding a space and/or adding 'AS'.

e.g.

```
(select ... from ...) X

(select ... from ...) AS X
```

Also, I see why the second where clause is there now.  :P

Comment: I used <> and AS X but the website says the answer has too many rows i.e., it is incorrect. 

        Select distinct yr 
From (Select distinct yr, subject From nobel Where subject<>'Chemistry') AS X
Where subject='Physics'

Comment: When you say `(select distinct yr, subject from nobel where subject <> 'Chemistry')`, you're going to get too many years.  That query is assuming that only one prize is given per year, which looks to not be the case... for example, if there was a Chemistry prize in 1901, you exclude that... but if there is also a Literature prize in 1901, you're going to get 1901 in your result set.  Basically, you're excluding **records** with a Chemistry prize, but you're not necessarily excluding **years** with a Chemistry prize.

Comment: Ah! I see. "Too many rows" makes sense now. Thank you for the explanation! :D

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the **X** in the query and why you're using `!=` instead of `<>`?

```
From (Select distinct yr, subject From nobel Where subject!='Chemistry')X
```

Just change it to the following code:

```
select distinct yr 
    from (select distinct yr, subject From nobel where subject <> 'Chemistry')
    Where subject='Physics'
```

Comment: When I don't write Alias name for the sub-query returned table , the result box on the website says alias required. And I have tried it with <>, its not working.